# How to make a class bean optional to use in other modules

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am making a EventService jar library for other two modules use. The source code that I build to a jar library have class below.

```
public class DatabaseConfig {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private int maximumPoolSize;
    
    public DatabaseConfig(String username, String password, int maximumPoolSize) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.maximumPoolSize = maximumPoolSize;
    }
    
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername (String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword (String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public int getMaximumPoolSize() {
        return maximumPoolSize;
    }
    public void setMaximumPoolSize (int maximumPoolSize) {
        this.maximumPoolSize = maximumPoolSize;
    }
}
```

```
public class DatabasePublisher {
    private final DatabaseConfig databaseConfig;
    private final String name;
    private final String email;

    public DatabasePublisher(DatabaseConfig databaseConfig, String name, String email) {
        this.databaseConfig = databaseConfig;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
    
    public String getDatabaseConfig() {
        return databaseConfig;
    }
    public void setDatabaseConfig (DatabaseConfig databaseConfig) {
        this.databaseConfig = databaseConfig;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail (String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

```
public class EventService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventService.class);

    private final DatabasePublisher databasePublisher;
    private final String eventName;
    private final int totalMessage;

    public EventService(DatabasePublisher databasePublisher, String eventName, int totalMessage) {
        this.databasePublisher = databasePublisher;
        this.eventName = eventName;
        this.totalMessage = totalMessage;
    }
    
    public void handleEvent() {
        //TO DO
    }
}
```

I have two modules use this library: ReceiveEventMessage1 and ReceiveEventMessage2.

I only want ReceiveEventMessage1 use the DatabasePublisher in the library and do not want to use it in ReceiveEventMessage2. So I only make a configuration for DatabasePublisher in ReceiveEventMessage1 and it run normally.
But if I do not make this configuration for ReceiveEventMessage2 module, it will throw the issue below when I run the ReceiveEventMessage2 app:

```
Parameter 5 of constructor in com.eventApp.EventService required a bean of type 'com.eventApp.DatabasePublisher' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.eventApp.DatabasePublisher' in your configuration.
```

I do not want to make a DatabasePublisher configuration for ReceiveEventMessage2. So I need to refactor DatabasePublisher class in the EventService library to use DatabasePublisher optional.

Anyone can give me solution for this case? I used @Lazy and @ConditionalOnProperty for DatabasePublisher class but it not effective. My idea is create a DatabaseConfig empty bean but I do not know how to do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating a library for other applications to use , it should be designed as generic as possible such that it can work with all cases that you need to support which is with and without  `DatabasePublisher` in your case.  For example, you can provide different static factory methods on it to create an instance for different cases , something like:

```java
public class EventService {

  
  public static EventService newInstanceWithDatabasePublisher(DatabasePublisher databasePublisher,String eventName, int totalMessag){
  }
  
  public static EventService newInstanceWithoutDatabasePublisher(String eventName, int totalMessag){

  }

}
```

Then let the clients to define how to create `DatabasePublisher` using `@Bean` method.

So for `ReceiveEventMessage1` :

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    

    @Bean
    public EventService eventService(){
       return EventService.newInstanceWithDatabasePublisher(...,...,..); 
    }

}
```

And `ReceiveEventMessage2` :

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    

    @Bean
    public EventService eventService(){
       return EventService.newInstanceWithoutDatabasePublisher(...,...,..); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but my requirement is that not add more any code in ReceiveEventMessage2. So I consider refactoring in library code only so that springboot can ignore EventService bean when ReceiveEventMessage2 run.

Answer (score 0):

If `DatabasePublisher` is an optional dependency of `EventService`, you can use [setter injection instead of constructor injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-constructor-vs-setter-injection).